# Trouble on inserting router-link to <li> with v-for VUE2.0

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Im working on a project which there is a list menu while i try to click the menu it will trigger a list of subMenu which allow us to router link to a particular link that we want to display. However i did alot of research mostly they are writing dead like this :

```
<ul>
  <router-link v-for="route in this.$router.options.routes" tag="li" :to="route.path">
    <a>{{ route.name }}</a>
  </router-link>
</ul>
```

Which are not useful for me as i need to set router-link by each for the v-for loop.

Below of this HTML is the one i need archieve the router-link on child.text

my HTML :

```
ul v-show='item.expanded' class="childs">
                            <li v-for='child in item.children'>
                                <a href="#">{{child.text}}</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
```

Main JS :

```
const Home = resolve => require(['./components/home.vue'], resolve)
const trafficSetting = resolve => require(['./components/trafficSetting.vue'], resolve)
const seedResourcesManagement = resolve => require(['./components/seedResourcesManagement.vue'], resolve)
const driverUserManagement = resolve => require(['./components/driverUserManagement.vue'], resolve)
const whiteblackListManagement = resolve => require(['./components/whiteblackListManagement.vue'], resolve)
const VPNserverManagement = resolve => require(['./components/VPNserverManagement.vue'], resolve)
const routes = [
    {path: '/', component: Home},
    {path: '/trafficSetting', component: trafficSetting},
    {path: '/seedResourcesManagement', component: seedResourcesManagement},
    {path: '/driverUserManagement', component: driverUserManagement},
    {path: '/whiteblackListManagement', component: whiteblackListManagement},
    {path: '/VPNserverManagement', component: VPNserverManagement}
]
```

Question : How do we get the router-link to called the main.js routes path on each data from child.text

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<li v-for='child in item.children'>
  <a href="#" v-on:click.prevent="navigate(chidl.text)">
    {{child.text}}
  </a>
</li>
```

and then, in your methods:

```
navigate (to) {
  this.$router.push(to)
}
```

See more details [here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html)

Comment: indeeds the methods you trying to push the route to the specified location path however does the navigate able to router certainly of the loop in array of each routes?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you, can you rephrase the question?

Comment: alright , i try to make this clear to you as i really need your help on this issue. As you know i try to loop the specified v-for for the particular child.text and it's show a list of subMenu which the subMenu i need to set a router-link for each value of the subMenu , does this make you clear ?